# Publishing a windows service to an application server using the publish wizard in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: windows, windows-services, publishing

All I want to do is what the title of my question says. I don't want to publish it to a website. I need to publish it to an apllication server where many windows services reside.

Every topic that I look up on the web has it where I need to publish to a website.

Can someone please inform me how I can accomplish this? By simply publishing it to an application server with the steps outlined or a possible link that actually easily explains this?